# CSS - How to position multiple images

Tags: css, image, positioning

I'm looking to learn how I can position images in CSS, multiple ones, without affecting my footers position, size, etc.

I coded some CSS I thought would work, but it messed up my footers position. (It wouldn't stay at the bottom.)
So, I fixed that issue but found the code I wrote for the image position messed with the footers position.
I don't really know how, but I would like to have my images positioned, perhaps by px/space.. they just need to look good in a row spaced.

The example is in red, is how I want it to look. 
[look here for an example of how I want it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYUF5.png)
**HTML**

```
<div class="batesimg">
<p><strong>Bates</p></strong>
<div class="shadow"> <!-- makes a shadow, surrounding the characters picture. -->
<img src="images/bates.png" alt="Bates" width="150" height="150"> <!-- defines the img -->
```

**CSS**

```
/* Bates profile picture. */
.batesimg { /* or whatever class name works for you */
position: auto;
left:250px;
top:250px;
margin-right: 500px;
}
```

**NOTE, the css above isn't positioning the image how i want it, showed in the image example, can someone help me positiong the image like i have it in my example image?
 Thanks!**

Comment: which example....add html css...

Comment: Sorry will update it, trying to add an image also.

Comment: code please.....

Comment: Best thing for you to learn is flex here. https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/

Comment: `position:auto` is ***invalid***. It errors and defaults to `static`. Without a set (and valid) `position`, `left` and `top` do not apply. So, from all the code in your example, the only one that actually does something is `margin-right:500px`. Besides, without any context, your question is not answerable. Please include a [mcve] as well as clear indications of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to repeat same type of pattern of name,img and descriptions. We will call this 'card'. Now you have two problems in hand.

1) Placing multiple cards in page. For this use some layout like flexbox.

2) Setting inside of card properly..

```css
/*1st Problem*/
#flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#flex-container>div.card{
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
/*1st Problem ends*/

/*2nd Problem*/
.card{
  width: 200px;
  height:calc(200px + 2em);
}
.card>.name ,.card>.desc{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.card>div.img{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
/*2nd Problem ends*/

.card:nth-child(1) div.img{background-color: red;}
.card:nth-child(2) div.img{background-color: green;}
.card:nth-child(3) div.img{background-color: blue;}
.card:nth-child(4) div.img{background-color: yellow;}


/*Centering Content*/
#flex-container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*top,bottom both zero.. and left,right both auto..
  handling margin is complicated..read about them
  */
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="name">Name1</div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="desc">Desc1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="name">Name2</div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="desc">Desc2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="name">Name3</div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="desc">Desc3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="name">Name4</div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="desc">Desc4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For any other problem visit [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: *"Try this"* type of answers without any explanation about what the problem is and how the code posted addresses it are considered low quality on SO as their teaching value is `null`. Besides, if any such snippet contains faulty code, the lack of explanation favors spreading the fault, especially when the code fixes something but breaks something else. Please see [answer] for details.

Comment: Additionally, you shouldn't have ventured an answer because the question is *"unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem."*.

Comment: Thanks! pretty much what I'm looking for, EXCEPT I want it to the right more. centered, pretty much. Image: http://i.imgur.com/m8glKOc.png

Comment: hmmm, well, something is broken for me with your code.
image: http://i.imgur.com/7wcvRMe.png
now when i remove some code: `.card{
  width: 200px;
  height:400px;
`
it shows this: http://i.imgur.com/ZTDOL6X.png
in short, **Removing that code i pasted above fixes my footer, (it stays on bottom correctly like it used to.) i don't know why it messed up my footer xD

Comment: Oh, also, when I paste the code you gave me that's updated, it looks like this. http://i.imgur.com/etYVvQc.png
Zoomed: 67% in browser

Comment: Hmmm, all I need is to figure out how to center the images properly and have them setup nicely you know? can you help me more with this? (made some changes to my footer and such.)
The current look of the page: http://i.imgur.com/aJdfqZu.png
p.s. I appreciate the help!

Comment: provided a way to center the content... I think its time to close this question..

Comment: You helped me a lot and fixed my issue, sorry for the late reply! +1 and closed.